# how to integrate spark streaming spark-2.1.0 with kafka 2.11-0.10.2.0 correctly in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I tried using spark streaming to process kafka messages,followed this wiki https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html
and my code is below:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaWordCount").setMaster("spark://sl:7077");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));
Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.1.5:9092");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
Collection<String> topics = Collections.singletonList("test");
final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
    stream.print();
```

after submit, it returns :

```
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: print at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:47
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (print at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:47) with 1 output partitions
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (print at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:47)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (KafkaRDD[0]     at createDirectStream at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:44), which has no missing parents
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in     memory (estimated size 2.3 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1529.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.245.226.155:15258 (size: 1529.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (KafkaRDD[0] at createDirectStream at     JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:44)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.245.226.155:53448) with ID 0
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.245.226.155, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7295 bytes)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.245.226.155:14669 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 10.245.226.155, 14669, None)
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.245.226.155:53447) with ID 1
17/04/05 22:43:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.245.226.155:33754 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 10.245.226.155, 33754, None)
17/04/05 22:43:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.245.226.155, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.decodeFileNameInURI(Utils.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:434)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:508)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:500)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:500)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:257)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

can someone help on it? thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the parameters passed to spark-submit?

You might have passed a jar-file name instead of an absolute path to the jar file. The class `org.apache.spark.executor.Executor` tries to load "Added Jars" and "Added Files" in `updateDependencies` method, but the URI path is not as presumed by spark.